# API searchCriteria not filter properly in status orders

Tags: api

I am calling orders using REST API, when I call this url:

> rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria

It works fine, and return all orders to me... but I need to filter by status, I am using:

```
rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=status&
                              searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=complete&
                              searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq
```

This just return false, but I have orders complete on Magento. I tried with other status value and conditions types, but with no success.

Comment: eghad, how does the authentication for these apis work? I'm using postman and it appears the tokens match the oauth1 fiels but it still comes back 401 unauthorized

Answer (score 2):

you can try as following :

```
/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=complete&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq
```

There is ?searchCriteria before SearchCriteria filters.

For more information you can refer : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/webapi/search-criteria.html

Comment: Page Not Found
Sorry!
The page you are looking for could not be found or the documentation does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking around and I believe the issue is `[conditionType]=eq`, which seems to only compare ints and not Strings. Instead, try `[conditionType]=like`, which worked for me. The request would look like:

```
rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=status&
                          searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=complete&
                          searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=like
```

A year late, but I was encountering the same problem, so hopefully some others might see this in the future.